# How to reattach an image to a ref dynamically without using the upload html popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Usually when you upload an image using an input field as:

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" ref="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Choose file...</label>
</div>
```

You can access the file as:

```
this.$refs.image.files[0]
```

But what happens if I wish to change this.$refs.image.files[0] dynamically without using the upload popup form please?

I tried this:

```
this.$refs.image = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/storage/images/image-gallery/' + imageUrl;
```

This

```
this.$refs.image.src = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/storage/images/image-gallery/' + imageUrl;
```

But it fails, any idea how to crack this one please?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like this issue is hard to resolve, no one answering it :-(